# findViewById throws null when called through an object

Tags: java, android

I have a function in `main.java` that uses some UI elements like spinner to textview.

```
public void updateNearByPeople() {
        reportEventPeopleAroundSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.peopleAround);
        …
}
```

When I call this function from within class, it works fine.

But when I call this function from another `class2.java` through an `object` `findViewById` throws `java.lang.NullPointerException`

If I make the function and all variables in it `static` than it also works fine while calling from `class2.java` but it doesn’t work with object calls.

How can I solve this and made of object aware of the context?

In `main.java`:

```
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_view);

    mainAppContext = this;
    Main mainObj=new Main();
    gMapObj.initiateMap(mainAppContext,mainObj, mapFrag);
}
```

In `class2.java`:

```
public boolean initiateMap(Context appContext, Main mainObj, MapFragment mapFrag) {
        mainAppContext = appContext;
        mainAppObject = mainObj;
        …
        mainAppObject.updateNearByPeople();
    }
```

Comment: yes it is an activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Main mainObj=new Main();
```

you can't do that. The activity needs to go through its lifecycle, to build up its view hierarchy. If you just instantiate it through the new operator, neither its onAttach or onCreate method will be called. It means that you can not access resources and views as well

Comment: Than how do i call functions from different classes here?