# Calling a function of an activity class through a different class

Tags: java, android

I want to call a function the belongs to an activity class and use resources from a different class.

How can i do that? I tried doing it my making an `object` of the activity class but [that doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25041625/findviewbyid-throws-null-when-called-through-an-object).

So what is the other possible way i can achieve this?

---

I have passed the `context (this)` of main class to other class through this. But how do i use it back?

```
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
        getActionBar().hide();
        setContentView(R.layout.main_view);

        mainAppContext = this;
        Main mainObj=new Main();
        gMapObj.initiateMap(mainAppContext,mainObj, mapFrag); //Control shifted to other class.

    }
```

Comment: You need to pass a reference from that Activity to other class. I dont know what your class is based on but you can get context or application context and reach activity from there

Comment: I have already made the main activities context available in the other class hwo do i use it now there, thats what i dont know.

Comment: Show me your code from other activity. How do you pass it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand correctly your question but this is my recommendation as far as I understood.

You shouldn't create object. You want to call a method on a instantiated activity. When you create object you will lose all your connection with the activity.

You can make your method `static` and then call it.

If you activity is `MainActivity`, create `public static void someMethod()` in this activity and call it from another class like this `MainActivity.someMethod()`

If you are able to pass reference do this instead, pass your context as parameter.

**EDIT**

This is how you should be doing:

```
public class SecondClass extends Activity {
    protected Context context;

    public SecondClass(Context context){
        this.context = context;
    }

    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
        getActionBar().hide();
        setContentView(R.layout.main_view);

        context.initiateMap(mainAppContext,mainObj, mapFrag);

    }

}
```

In your Activity do this

```
new SecondClass(this);
```

Comment: my `MainActivity` class is the activity and `SecondClass` is just a simple class. When in `initiateMap` function i try to do this `this=mainAppContext` i get an error that `The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable`.

Comment: Because you can't do `this = mainAppContext`. `this` is not a variable. Look at the code I posted and do like it. In my code I put `this.context = context;` and I declared `context` on top.

Comment: how can i call a function with a context variable? its not a instance of the class? its a context right? Plus as i said above my situation is vice versa of your solution. my MainActivity class is the activity and SecondClass is just a simple class. the `initiateMap` map funtion is in seconClass but called from MainActivity.

Comment: You said `I want to call a function the belongs to an activity class`. Now you are saying your function is in `SecondClass`. If your `initiateMap` is in `SecondClass` and you are calling it from the activity, your first approach was correct. You can create object and call it you don't have to pass reference. And explain us what do you mean by "It doesn't work". It might be anything.

Comment: if you read my question, i have linked another questions there asked my regarding that issue of why its not working.